# How do I generate prerending pages in Angular

Tags: angular, seo, server-side-rendering

I have application for real estate agency and client want better SEO optimization I know that maybe best solution is SSR and that is not problem. I want to implement prerending page for example:

I have filter page for real estates /filter?q=someQuery
That query sends request on the backend for filtering real estates, but how I can implement page like /house-on-sale-berlin ? In the background of that page we want to send queryBuilder but the main purpose is to have pages like that for better optimization

Answer (score 0):

so prerendering static pages would allow you to fetch even data from the server (does not work with websocket btw).

You can check https://angular.io/guide/prerendering

I would also suggest adding a file of routes to be prerendered where you can add all pages to be prerendered(with their data fetching if needed).

In package json:

```
"prerender": "ng run srr-app:prerender --routesFile angularprerender.txt",
```

in angularprerender.txt

```
/
/privacy-policy
/contact
/about-us
/house-on-sale-berlin
```

Comment: Thanks, I how I can add data for fetching ?